# How to solve increasing memory consumption when fetch rows in sql?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I use pyodbc for insert or read from SQL server DB and I have 32 GB ram on my pc, when I insert data to my DB The amount of rum used is as follows.
[image: ram usage when insert information]

But when I read rows from db as shown as  my ram is very high usage :

Code:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('''
                      TRUSTED_CONNECTION=Yes;
                      DRIVER={SQL Server};
                      SERVER={myServer};
                      DATABASE=myDB;''')
id=[1,345,34,78,45,768]
cursor = conn.cursor()

for numberid in id:
       sqlquery ="SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table.db WHERE COLUMN.2 = %s "   %(numberid ) 
       cursor.execute(sqlquery )
       answer=cursor.fetchall()
       print(answer)
          
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

[image: ram usage when read rows from DB]

I use  `cursor.close() ,conn.close()`  However, the amount of RAM used does not decrease even after closing the application, and the amount of RAM used each day increases slightly. If the my PC is restarted, the amount of RAM usage will be clear.
How do I fix this problem?
pyodbc version :4.0.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior for SQL Server.

SQL Server will cache all the rows it reads from disk, increasing its memory usage up to the configured [MAX SERVER MEMORY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15#manually), or until the operating system signals that it is short of available memory.

If you have a big database and lots of other programs running on the computer and want to limit SQL Server's memory you can do it with SSMS, or buy running a batch like:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'show advanced options', N'1';
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'max server memory (MB)', N'4096';
RECONFIGURE;
```

Comment: That is right. I run my code in SQL managment and use 60% of ram then this is not memory leak on pyodbc or python. sql server cash results for next users if they need this results and if memory was 100%, sql serverclean old cash for new results.  SQL Server has full Memory Management and provides SQL Server immediately when Windows needs memory.
Of course, this does not mean that SQL Server replaces Windows in memory management! Rather, they work perfectly together. I set 28 GB to sql server with this tutorial video`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z__A6MuhNEc`